# Flutter AutoCompleteTextField: Tab through list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this auto complete flutter package. https://pub.dev/packages/autocomplete_textfield

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:**
I am designing this application for an android tablet that will use a bluetooth keyboard.

I have managed to implement it successfully, but was wondering if there was a way to:

1. Cycle through the list that pops up using a keyboard's tab-key and accept the entry with enter. Right now the only way to accept an option is with a mouse click/touch.
2. Highlight an option when moving over it with the mouse point/tab-cycle

[image]

Comment: Are you going to use in web?

Comment: Apologies. I should have clarified that. No, this is an application for an android tablet that will be using a bluetooth keyboard

Comment: No Apologies bro just asked to confirm before reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a ticket open for this https://github.com/felixlucien/flutter-autocomplete-textfield/issues/62

Currently it doesn't support.

Comment: Thanks for this. That is really unfortunate as it does remove a huge amount of ease-of-use. Pity no one has replied to this either.